# How to prevent XSS attack from the ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, xss

In my application, In the Master page, I have set values to the JavaScript variable as follows,

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" Inherits="Web.Common.Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var BRANCH_NAME = "<% =BranchName%>";
        var USER_ID = "<% =UserId %>";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are another page to manage(input) Location details, and when user input this ( **`";alert("s");"`**)  kind of vulnerable scripts, its render as popup in whole application. browser response shows as follows,

[image]

How can I handle this type of XSS? is this handle when input branch name? or any other way? please give me idea to solve this.

Comment: I don't know about ASP but if you have a value provided by user and you have to display that value, you should always escape it before visualising it. In this case lets say, you want your BRANCH_NAME to contain only letters, numbers and _, so you can just add a regex which trims everything else from the BranchName variable before assigning it to BRANCH_NAME.
TLDR; There is no magic way to prevent all XSS attacks, so you should think about it depending on where you use the user input.

Comment: Normally you would use the `<%:  %>` to escape the `<script>` tags which a user might inject into your app. But in this case you've already done that so the clever user has out witted you. In this case use hidden fields and access them in your JS and that should prevent it. Think that each input from user a potential security hazard.

Comment: @SalikRafiq Can u please provide me sample code to explain what u said

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices here.

One is check all the user input for anything dodgy. This could be difficult in your circumstance since in most cases the checking is for things like `<script>`, `<embed>` and this would miss something like 'alert' because that's a english word.

Second is ensure all output is escaped.
This is the most common solution in my experience. Typically this is accomplished by using the `<%: %>` in the controls (`<%#: %>` for bound controls)**
** there is a set of controls where this escaping isn't required eg: textbox

To solve your specific situation above, don't trust the user input.

Use hidden fields and have the JS access it.

```
<body>
.
.
.
  <asp:hiddenfield id="hdnBRANCH_NAME" runat="server" value='<%# BranchName %>' />
  <asp:hiddenfield id="hdnUSER_ID" runat="server" value='<%# UserId %>'/>
.
.
<script>
   var branch_name = document.getElementById('<%= hdnBRANCH_NAME.ClientID%>').value;
   //similar for UserId
</script>
```

Note: you can assign the hidden fields from the code-behind as well.